# Dynamically pass Hash value to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, render, partials

I faced a problem to pass the hash value to partial file dynamically. I displayed the person names on my page (this is a partial). The hash value is like this:

```
names[1] = "James"  
names[2] = "Williams"  
names[3] = "Jack"  

render :partial => "list", :locals => {:names => names}
```

I need to pass the hash value dynamically. How can I do that? In the example, the new hash is like this:

```
names[21] = 'Flink'  
names[81] = 'Mark'
```

### My code

```
class PrlcController < ApplicationController
def bar
  @names = Hash.new
  @names[1] = "James"  
  @names[2] = "Williams"  
  @names[3] = "Jack"  
end

def foo_ajax
  @names = Hash.new
  @names[21] = 'Flink'  
  @names[81] = 'Mark'
end

end

bar.rhtml
----------

<!-- Name listing section -->
<%= render :partial => "list", :locals => "{:names => @names}" %>

<!-- AJAX calling section -->
<%= link_to_function "call testing", :onclick => "load_foo_ajax_data" %>


<!-- AJAX section -->
<div id="foo_ajax_data">
</div>

<!-- script section -->
function load_foo_ajax_data() {
       new Ajax.Updater("foo_ajax_data","/Prlc/foo_ajax", {
            asynchronous:true,
            evalScripts:true,
            onComplete:function(request){             
            },
            onLoading:function(request){}
        });
}


foo_ajax.rhtml
--------------
Some process here.


_list.rhtml
-----------
Display the names
```

Comment: What do you mean you need to "*pass* the *hash value* in *dynamically*"? It'd help if you didn't make up jargon.

Comment: Yes @coreyward. I need to pass the hash value in dynamically to the partial file.

Comment: when is this hash value changing _dynamically_ ?

Comment: In my page, i called one AJAX, when it complete the hash value will changed. So, immediately i need to update the name listing also.

Comment: What you need is to reload it - if you're using rjs maybe using something like "page.replace_html" would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
class PrlcController < ApplicationController
  def bar
    @names = Hash.new
    @names[1] = "James"  
    @names[2] = "Williams"  
    @names[3] = "Jack"  
  end

  def foo_ajax
    @names = Hash.new
    @names[1] = 'Flink'  
    @names[2] = 'Mark'
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html  'foo_ajax_data', :partial => "list", :object => [@names]
    end
  end

end
```

### bar.rhtml

```
<%= render :partial => "list", :locals => "{:names => @names}" %>    

<!-- AJAX section -->
<div id="foo_ajax_data">
  <!-- Name listing section -->
</div>

<!-- AJAX calling section -->
<%= link_to_remote "call testing", :url => { :action => "load_foo_ajax_data"} %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Salil. But, it's not my answer. I need to update the [id]foo_ajax_data with foo_ajax.rhtml file. ":partial => list.." is the separate section. when foo_ajax calling finished, after update the listing section.